# How do I use Ctrl + End to go to the last formatted cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Using Ctrl + End on a excel worksheet goes to the last cell in the range (moves in the direction of the arrow) that has some content in it. This usually ignores formatted cells. That is, if you're in cell A1 and you have copied a formatting that goes down to A13, you can't use Ctrl + End to jump down to A13.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the buttons <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>.

In the screenshot, the last populated cell is B3, but the format has been copied into C6, which extends the **used range** to that cell. You can get to the end of the used range by pressing <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> directly after one another.

There's no keyboard shortcut to jump to the last formatted cell in a row or column. The  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + arrow keys shortcut only jumps to the last cell that has content.

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- but what if the formatted cell was in, say, A6 or C1?

Comment: There is no keyboard shortcut for that. The Ctrl + Arrow keyboard shortcuts only jump to cells that have content.

Comment: Okay. I've added this comment to the answer so that I can mark this as answered. Please feel free to revert if you'd like.